# Python (BeautifulSoup) Only 1 result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know there are similar questions to this one that are answered which I already tried applying and didn't fix my problem.

My problem is that on this website: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html there are 20 prices and when I try to scrape the prices, I only get the first price but not other 19.

Here's the code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "col-sm-8 col-md-9")

for i in results :
    prices = i.find("p", class_ = "price_color")
    print(prices.text.strip())
    print()
```

Comment: What is the value of `page.content`? Can you strip it down to the bare minimum that should still work but doesn't? See how to create a [mcve], and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72675941/edit) the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

list_of_books = soup.select(
    # using chrom selector
    '#default > div > div > div > div > section > div:nth-child(2) > ol > li'
)

for book in list_of_books:
    price = book.find('p', {'class': 'price_color'})
    print(price.text.strip())
```

i just used chorme selector
[this is a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjS4T.png)

you are using the `find` and `find_all` in the wrong places.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation. I am new to web scraping and this really means to me!

Comment: Why didn't OP's code work?

Comment: @PeterWood OP's code doesn't work because it searc wrong item - there is only one `div` with many `prices` but it exepect many `divs` and every `div` with single `price`. See my answer.

Comment: @furas I know that. But the question didn't give the contents of the HTML, and this answer doesn't help explain why OP's code didn't work, or why this answer does work.

Answer (score 1):

You search items in wrong way.

There is only one `div` with `col-sm-8 col-md-9` with many `prices` but your code expects many `divs` with single price in every `div` - and this makes problem.

Using `find()` you search single price in this `div` but you should use `find_all` to get all prices in this single `div`.

```
div = soup.find("div", class_="col-sm-8 col-md-9")

prices = div.find_all("p", class_="price_color")

for i in prices:
    print(i.text.strip())
```

You could even search directly prices

```
prices = soup.find_all("p", class_="price_color")

for i in prices:
    print(i.text.strip())
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

div = soup.find("div", class_="col-sm-8 col-md-9")

prices = soup.find_all("p", class_="price_color")

for i in prices:
    print(i.text.strip())
```

---

Using `find()` to search price could work only if you would first find all regions with single price - like `article`.

Every book is in separated `article` - so there are many `articles` and every `article` has single price (and single title, single image, etc.)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("article")

for i in results:
    title = i.find("h3")
    print('title:', title.text.strip())

    price = i.find("p", class_="price_color")
    print('price:', price.text.strip())

    print('---')
```

Result:

```
title: A Light in the ...
price: £51.77
---
title: Tipping the Velvet
price: £53.74
---
title: Soumission
price: £50.10
---
title: Sharp Objects
price: £47.82
---
title: Sapiens: A Brief History ...
price: £54.23
---
title: The Requiem Red
price: £22.65
---
title: The Dirty Little Secrets ...
price: £33.34
---
title: The Coming Woman: A ...
price: £17.93
---
title: The Boys in the ...
price: £22.60
---
title: The Black Maria
price: £52.15
---
title: Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade ...
price: £13.99
---
title: Shakespeare's Sonnets
price: £20.66
---
title: Set Me Free
price: £17.46
---
title: Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little ...
price: £52.29
---
title: Rip it Up and ...
price: £35.02
---
title: Our Band Could Be ...
price: £57.25
---
title: Olio
price: £23.88
---
title: Mesaerion: The Best Science ...
price: £37.59
---
title: Libertarianism for Beginners
price: £51.33
---
title: It's Only the Himalayas
price: £45.17
---
```

Comment: I like this explanation as well, thank you for letting me know these things!